# Donut Multiple from react-donut-component not rendering after deployment

Tags: reactjs, donut-chart

I have coded a donut multiple chart in my react application which is perfectly working fine in local but once deployed to server its gone without a trace. Code as below

```
import {
  Donut,
  DonutMultiple,
  DonutElement,
  DonutLabel,
} from "react-donut-component";

<div className="row">
                    <div className="col-6 chart">
                      <Donut>100</Donut>;
                      <DonutMultiple
                        animate
                        linecap="round"
                        size={250}
                        strokeWidth={5}
                      >
                        <DonutElement color="green" name="Correct Answers">
                          {this.state.correct_answers}
                        </DonutElement>
                        <DonutElement color="#FF0000" name="Incorrect Answers">
                          {this.state.wrong_answers}
                        </DonutElement>
                        <DonutElement
                          color="#EA9564"
                          name="Unattempted Questions"
                        >
                          {this.state.questions_skipped}
                        </DonutElement>
                        <DonutLabel
                          styleSymbol={{
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                            fontSize: "18px",
                          }}
                        >
                          Marks: {this.state.x}
                        </DonutLabel>
                      </DonutMultiple>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-6 examDetails mb-2">
                      <p className="card-title-top text-capitalize">
                        <p className=" text-capitalize">
                          Attempt Count :{" "}
                          {this.state.messageInfo.results.attempt}{" "}
                        </p>
                      </p>
                     code here
                      <a
                        href={"/exam-report?result_id=" + this.state.result_id}
                        className="btn btn--wide"
                      >
                        Review Questions
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Version used: "react-donut-component": "^2.2.6",
[image]

I am kind of clueless here and any help is much appreciated.
[image]